# configuring Java 9 in JNLP

Tags: java-web-start, jnlp

The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/deploy/jnlp-file-syntax.htm) say I can configure the Java 9 platform in JNLP like this:

```
<j2se version="9" ... />
```

However if I do so and try to run it using Java 9.0.4 I get a warning saying the requested Java version (9) is not installed. My code:

```
<j2se version="9" java-vm-args="-Xmx1g" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
```

If I do this instead, there is no such popup:

```
<j2se version="9.*" ... />
```

But I cannot find such a "*" wildcard in the specs. What is going on?

Comment: Did you try "9+" ?

Comment: "9+" works but does not exclude (the platform) Java 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what's wrong. My example was incomplete, because I did not mention the **href** attribute I was using in the **j2se** element.

Solution: In contrast to versions, **platforms must be specified without** href attributes.

> If a platform version is specified (that is, no href attribute is
>   provided)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/deploy/jnlp-file-syntax.htm

Fixed element (for the example in the question):

```
<j2se version="9" java-vm-args="-Xmx1g"/>
```